# Использование TableView с неизменяемыми объектами. Ошибка бесконечного цикла

Tags: java, javafx

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:**
Имеется список неизменяемых объектов. Необходимо отобразить этот список в виде таблице `TableView` через которую также можно будет его редактировать. Часть полей неизменяемых объектов представлены в виде целых чисел и должны отображаться в ячейках таблицы в виде элемента `Spiner`.

**С чем возникли сложности:**
У объектов есть несколько операций позволяющих задать значение для некоторых полей или выполнить какие-то вычисления. Поскольку объекты неизменяемы - каждая такая операция создает и возвращает новый объект этого же типа содержащий все внесенные изменения. И тут есть два момента:

1. Необходимо заменить старую версию объекта на новую в списке элементов таблицы. Список элементов таблицы представлен типом `ObservableList`, так что когда он будет изменен `TableView` автоматически обнавиться.
2. Теперь важный момент со `Spiner`. Единственный способ подписаться на события от этого элемента, это подписаться на прослушивание событий от его свойства - `spiner.valueProperty().addListener(...)`. Событие будет срабатывать ВСЕГДА, КОГДА ИЗМЕНЯЕТСЯ ЭТО СВОЙСТВО.

В сумме эти два момента дают следующее: клиент взаимодействует со спинером -> изменяется его свойство `valueProperty()` -> вызывается слушатель этого свойства -> слушатель изменяет объект текущей строки таблицы и его новую версию записывает в список элементов таблицы -> список (напомню - его тип  `ObservableList`) уведомляет таблицу что он был изменен -> таблица обновляется, обновляя значение каждой ячейки измененной строки и таким образом обновляет свойство `valueProperty()` нашего спинера -> цепочка начинается сначала...

Самое интересное, что когда таблица обновляет свойство `valueProperty()` спинера, передаваемое таблицей значение автоматически изменяется в зависимости от последней используемой операции со спинером(клиент нажал стрелку "увеличить" или "уменьшить").

**Вопрос:** как решить проблему бесконечного цикла обновлений?

P.s. этот пример хорошо демонстрирует главную опасность использования паттерна наблюдатель.

Comment: а если эту часть полей представить не в виде  целых чисел, а самостоятельных неизменяемых объектов, не поможет? может так соседние спинеры избегут инвалидации?

Comment: ваш вариант будет работать, если эти самостоятельные неизменяемые объекты не будут частью неизменяемых объектов в списке отображения TableView. Но это очень неудобно в использовании. Но главная проблема - мне бы не хотелось вносить изменения в архитектуру модели из-за представления.

Comment: Если отказаться от какого-либо наблюдателя (таблицы или спинера) и управлять ими по генерируемым событиям собственного EventBus механизма? Если заменить полностью таблицу на ListView с кастомной реализацией сложной строки (это даст большую управляемость элементами)?

Comment: Насчет первого варианта: вы не можете отказаться от наблюдателей. Добавив Spiner как ячейку в TableView, он де-факто подписывается на события изменения элементов TabaleView и поменять это нельзя. Управлять содержимым таблицы можно только через ObservableList для её элементов и отписать таблицу о события этого списка нельзя. К сожалению я не могу отказаться ни от TableView ни от Spiner и заменить их на что-то другое. Spiner обязательно должен быть ячейкой таблицы.

Comment: На счет второго варианта - ListView также хранит отображаемые элементы в ObservableList. Реализация сложной строки, которую вы предлагаете, должна быть реализацией ListCell. У ListCell есть метод updateItem(), который ListView будет вызывать всегда, когда посчитает нужным (прокрутка ListView, изменение списка элементов и другие случаи). Вы должны в updateItem() обновлять все элементы вашей сложной строки, если хотите чтобы их содержимое правильно отображалось при прокрутке. При обновлении элементов сложной строки вы будете обновлять из свойство valueProperty(). Получается та же цепочка.